# "I will give it that??" Is it naturally used?

Tags: phrases

When you say,
'He is short and not  good looking, but he is very smart. I will give him that.'
It means ' I admit he is smart although he is short and ugly'. Right?

But,
My question is when you say something about a thing ,not about someone..is the phrase 'i will give it that' used naturally?

For example,  'iPhone sucks for the most part but its design is cool. I will give it that.'

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The purpose of the site is to promote a wider understanding of the English Language and its usage, not to carry out personal vendettas against people, businesses or organisations. If you will chose a more neutral example I will be pleased to comment.

Comment: @WS2 he clearly asks about the use of language (without research, I'll give you that), no need to impose our 'moral high ground' on the question..

Comment: 'I will give him / her / them / it that' means 'I will concede that this is a good point about him / her / them / it'. It marks a concessive remark.   An example I might use: "It's an annoying cat, always fouling the garden – but it's a good mouser, I'll give it that." / And from the internet {[HouseBeautiful]}(https://www.housebeautiful.com/design-inspiration/g14426620/decor-trends-that-will-be-out-in-2018/)}, an example with a non-sentient referent:  "Granite is durable, I will give it that, but it lacks the beauty of marble or the sleekness of quartz ...".

Answer (score 0):

I've more commonly heard "I'll give you that." Which is an idiom in English.

Though I'll is I will, I think it is more grammarly correct with "I'll"

It also states in a trusted dictionary called, Merriam-Webster: "used to say that one is willing to admit that at least part of something someone says is true."

Example given from that dictionary:
"I don't really like his movies, but he's a talented actor, I'll give you that."

Comment: I like your answer except for the word grammarly. We would say grammatically correct. grammarly is an internet site.